# Convolution of shifted dirac delta's

Tags: convolution, dirac-delta

what is the result of $\delta(t-t_0)*\delta(t+t_0):$

$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(t+t_0-x)\delta(x-t_0)dx$

Im not sure how to proceed with that question. Normally when we use sifting property, the function is defined at at least where delta function lies. But these are distinct deltas where they are defined at distinct points. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: The formula does not correspond to the question. // Coming back at what delta measures and convolutions *mean*, one arrives readily at the answer to the question in the first line: $$\delta(t).$$

Comment: Your right, there was a typo. Anyway it is not clear for me. I know what the answer is, i want to learn how it was derived.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The convolution of two distributions $S, T \in \def\D{\mathcal D}\D'(\def \R{\mathbf R}\R)$, one of which has compact support, is the unique $S*T \in \D'(\R)$ such that 
$$ (S * T) * \varphi = S*(T*\varphi), \qquad \phi \in \D(\R) $$
Now, for $\varphi \in \D(\R)$, we have
\begin{align*}
  \delta(\cdot + t_0) * \varphi &= \varphi(\cdot + t_0)\\
  \delta(\cdot - t_0) * \bigl(\delta(\cdot + t_0) * \varphi\bigr) 
   &= \delta(\cdot - t_0) * \varphi(\cdot + t_0)\\
   &= \varphi
\end{align*}
Hence, $\delta(\cdot + t_0) * \delta(\cdot - t_0)$ is the unit of the convolution $\D(\R) \to \D(\R)$, that is, $\delta$. Hence
$$ \delta(\cdot + t_0) * \delta(\cdot -t_0) = \delta $$

---

*In other words*: As you wrote in your initial post, the result of the convolution of $\delta(\cdot + t_0)$ and $\delta(\cdot - t_0)$ cannot be computed by standard means as a function. So, we will try to see how it acts unter integration, it's like $\delta$ is defined by the property 
$$ \int_{\R} \delta(t)\phi(t)\, dt  = \phi(0) $$
for smooth functions $\phi$. So let $\phi$ be a smooth function, we have 
\begin{align*}
  \int_{\R} \varphi(t)\bigl(\delta(t + t_0) * \delta(t-t_0)\bigr)\, dt
   &= \int_{\R} \varphi(t)\int_\R \delta(t+ t_0 - x)\delta(x - t_0)\,dx\, dt\\
   &=\int_\R\int_\R \varphi(t)\delta(t+t_0-x)\, dt \,\delta(x-t_0) \,dx\\
   &= \int_\R \varphi(x-t_0)\delta(x-t_0)\, dx\\
   &= \varphi(0)
\end{align*}
So, for all smooth $\varphi$, we have
$$  \int_{\R} \varphi(t)\bigl(\delta(t + t_0) * \delta(t-t_0)\bigr)\, dt = \varphi(0) $$
that is $\delta(\cdot + t_0) * \delta(\cdot - t_0)$ has the same properties under integration as $\delta$. As this is the defining property
$$ 
\delta(\cdot + t_0) * \delta(\cdot - t_0) = \delta $$

Comment: Im electrical engineering student and my course does not offer course about distributions. Probably your answer is true but i couldn't understand this answer at all. If you can explain what is happening i will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So our background is quite different. As $\delta$ *is* a distribution, how do you define $\delta$ without talking about distributions?

Comment: Problem starts just here. Simply they want us to memorize some properties of dirac delta like sifting property, and then use it whenever we need. Or sometimes they just give the result, like here. Then every time i face with so called function i feel like i hit my head to wall. Because i want to understand system from it is foundations, all the model. I don't know what to say...

Comment: @Salihcyilmaz
So, I'd tried to write something in (hopefully) more easy notation. The idea behind $\delta$ (and other "functions", the mathematical name of these "generalized functions" is *distributions*), is that they only "make sense under an integral", it is they are defined by the way they act on other functions. $\delta$ is given by the property 
$$ \int_{\mathbf R} \delta(t)\phi(t) = \phi(0) $$
for smooth $\phi$ (the integral is abuse of notation, as $\delta$ is not really a function, but it is nice to read and use).

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. It is a lot clearer for me in this way...